# Mallorca's public transportation prices

Tags: transportation, tickets, buses, spain, fares

What are the current prices of public transportation bus and train services? Are there any monthly/weekly passes?

Comment: There are at least 2 companies in "Mallorca" providing public transportation. Are you refering to Palma de Mallorca (city) or to the island?

Comment: Just a thought, I think driving in Mallorca is the best way to get around this island.

Comment: @user4401 The bus network in Mallorca radiates out like a fan from the Capital - Palma. You can basically go anywhere by bus from Palma, the disadvantage being to go somewhere else you will have to go back to Palma, and then onward again.

Comment: I am referring to the whole island. Car is usually a good choice, but it's one of the most expensive at the same time.

Comment: I have been in Mallorca in 2004 and a really recommend to you rent a car. I don't know if you have checked the prices or if you are able to drive but if you can rent a car.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Balearic Islands Transport (Transports de les Illes Balears - TIB)** provides an extensive network of public buses throughout Mallorca and also operates the single line Palma Metro.

**EMT Palma de Mallorca (Empresa Municipal de Transports de Palma de Mallorca)** is responsible for bus services in the City of Palma and its surroundings. The website, in English, has interactive maps showing all routes. EMT also runs a Palma night bus.

**Tickets**

Passengers are recommended to have the exact change when boarding the bus: tickets cannot be purchased with a note valued at more than a €10.

More info:

http://www.emtpalma.es/EMTPalma/Front/tarifas.en.svr

Residents and non-residents can buy a Citizen Card, which allows holders to board the bus without having to pay cash. These can be bought from the Town Hall and also allow reduced fares.

More info:

http://www.emtpalma.es/EMTPalma/03_tarjeta.jsp?lng=uk

**Trains on Mallorca:**

The Majorca rail network on the Spanish Island of Mallorca has three lines to four destinations from the Estació Intermodal/Plaça d'Espanya station in Palma.

More info:

http://www.tib.org/en/web/ctm/tren

**Trams on Mallorca:**

There is just one old line that goes from Soller to Port de Soller. It is museum tram and a tourist attraction. You can buy tickets off the conductor; a single ride is around €3.

Additional Info:

Interactive Route Finder: http://www.emtpalma.es/EMTPalma/Front/como_ir.en.svr

Public Transportation (Buses, Trains etc) in Mallorca: http://www.tib.org/en/web/ctm/inici

Answer (score 2):

Check [the transit system website](http://www.tib.org) it has been fully updated.

You have all fares in each line page, plus a route planner (accessible from "home" page or "find your route" page).

This website also works for Menorca island.