# Day pass for public transportation in Berlin, Munich and Cologne

Tags: trains, germany, price

What is the cost of a 1 or 2 day public transportation pass in cities of Cologne, Berlin and Munich, Germany?

Comment: For inner city travel, roughly 9€ for one person per day, or 13€ for five persons riding together. If you want to reach adjacent towns, it's slightly more. Please be more specific which sights you want to see so we could give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Questions about prices for specific services are considered off topic here. You can find answers to all your questions with a few clicks on each transportation authority's web page.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Are you sure it's off-topic? We've got open, upvoted, answered questions on public transport prices for [Amsterdam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73849), [Stockholm](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26125), [Vienna](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/98783), [Singapore](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/103356), and [Mallorca](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/14571), amongst others.

Comment: @Pont Most of the questions you are linking to is about specific details of the different offers and not just a 'what does the ticket cost?' question. I would say that at least three close reasons apply here: Too broad, price shopping and travel agency service, and perhaps even a slight drizzle of 'lack of trivial self research'.

Comment: Welcome new user!  I actually liked your question  :)  I like Tor, but I like your question.  :)

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The Mallorca question, in its entirety, reads "What are the current prices of public transportation bus and train services? Are there any monthly/weekly passes?". This isn't price shopping because there's no price competition: there's only one supplier per city, charging fixed prices. Nor is it "travel agency service": no planning is requested, just specific information. As for the "triviality" of self-research: I got from https://www.cologne.de/transportation.html to the actual prices in about 12 clicks, but most of the intermediate pages were only available in German.

Comment: @Pont: While I appreciate your attempt of an answer, I think the question is much too unspecific and should be improved. It's also unlikely to be of worth for a long time, as fares change quite often.

Answer (score 1):

**Cologne:**

1 day: 7,10 € - 29,40 €.

Tourists usually use Ticket 1b (8,60 €) for "Köln (2100)".

- https://www.vrs-ticketshop.de/en/oxid/TagesTicket-1-Person.html
- https://www.kvb.koeln/tickets/tarifgebiete/koeln.html
- https://www.kvb.koeln/fahrtinfo/liniennetzplaene.html#lightbox/2/ (see "Touristenplan" for Ticket 1b)

**Munich:**

1 day: 6,70 € - 13,00 €. 3 days: 16,80 € (Innenraum/inner region only).

Tourist are usually fine with "Innenraum" (6,70 €). For the KZ in Dachau, you need "Munich XXL" (8,90 €). "CityTourCard" (1/2/3/4/5/6 days) and "MünchenCard" (1/2/3/4/5 days) offer discounts for tourist attractions.

- https://www.mvv-muenchen.de/en/tickets-and-fares/tickets-daytickets/index.html
- https://www.mvv-muenchen.de/fileadmin/mediapool/03-Plaene_Bahnhoefe/Tarifplaene/TARIFPLAN_Gesamtnetz_2018.PDF

**Berlin:**

1 day: 3,60 € - 21,00 €. 7 days: 13,10 € - 67,30 €.

Day passes for Berlin city are 7,00 € - 7, 70 €.

- https://www.vbb.de/en/tickets
- https://www.vbb.de/en/timetables/network-maps

There are also offers for tourists: "WelcomeCard" (2/3/4/5/6 days), "CityTourCard" (2/3/4/5 days), "EasyCityPass" (2/3/4/5/6 days), "QueerCityPass".

- https://www.vbb.de/fahrpreise/angebote-touristen
- https://www.berlin-welcomecard.de
- https://www.citytourcard.com
- http://www.easycitypass.com/en/city/berlin-en
- http://www.queercitypass.com/en/city/berlin-en

Answer (score 0):

For Cologne, I found [this page](https://www.vrs-ticketshop.de/en/oxid/TagesTicket-1-Person.html) listing prices for 1-day passes. According to the [Tarifberater](http://tarif.vrsinfo.de/tbv/vrs/cgi) (German only) the 1b price zone (€8.60) should get you the whole of Cologne -- I wasn't able to discover what the 1a zone would correspond to. [This page](https://www.kvb.koeln/tickets/welches_ticket/gelegenheitsfahrer/tagesticket.html) (German only) gives more information on the conditions of the ticket. In short, it lets you use all local transport and regional trains until 03:00 on the day after purchase.